# Automated API Versioning

Tags: .net, documentation, continuous-integration, github, versioning

I did research about this and I'm facing with two challenges:

1. how to handle version deprecation in my CI/CD pipeline, when we have more than one major versions officially functional and others deprecated.
2. how to handle documentation of the project

The project is a .net web API(uses Swashbuckle for docs) that uses GitHub actions to test, version and build final docker images with the new version as the image tag and push it to ghcr.io

**So far:**
I thought maybe I provide new version through an environment variable after GitHub action bumped the last version, but then how about documents?